# How to install Overture on Windows

Tags: vdm++

I'm running Widows 7 Professional on a 64-bit system with Java SE 10. I downloaded Overture-2.6.2-win32.win32x86-64.zip and unzipped it under c: and clicked on the Overture application. It started and asked for a workspace path. I took the default but it failed. The log file showed a bunch of Java errors include ClassNotFound. I moved the Overture folder to Program Files where the Java folder is. Failed again. The Overture manual indicates the download includes Eclipse. I removed the current Eclipse version in case that was the problem. Still failed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Overture download web page has the text "(Java SE 8 is required)" I took that to mean 8 or later. They meant **only 8 will work**. I had Java 10 (current version) installed. When I removed Java 10 and installed Java 8 Overture loaded. I hope this answer saves others the time I wasted.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback Alan. We're just about to release 2.6.4, so I've contacted the release manager to see whether we can at least squeeze in a change to the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the Overture 2.6.4 release candidate (which I will release on October 19, 2018) using Java 10 on Ubuntu, and I received the error shown below. It seems like this error is caused by the Eclipse version (Oxygen) that Overture builds against. By following the instructions found here https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9 I was able to fix the issue. Specifically by adding `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM` to the Overture.ini file. Does this solve your problem? Although the page was originally intended to cover Java 9 configuration it seems like the suggestions still work.

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=10.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-10-18 11:15:34.628
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
        ... 25 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-10-18 11:15:34.644
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
```

Comment: If that fixes a problem for some systems, we should add that to the INI file anyway, even if it's not Alan's specific issue.